# Install TortoiseHG on a shared drive?

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

Would it be possible to put install THG on a shared drive and let
users run it from there without having to install it locally on each
user's machine?

I'd be willing to accept some minor loss of functionality such as no
overlay icons or menus in Explorer. Maybe people can only use the
workbench interface...

Bonus points if the local stuff could be wired up after it was
installed centrally!

Comment: My initial reaction is that you're trying to do this to keep the version that everyone uses up-to-date and synchronized. My initial reaction is also that this will cause more pain than it's worth :)

Comment: Care to explain why would you need that?

Comment: Our group at work has a shared drive available to us that makes it convenient and quick to install software in a common place. We try to install all software there as much as possible. Going through the IT department at work to install it on everyone's machine can be slow. It makes it easier to manage by having one installation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got [an answer](http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/forum.php?thread_name=CACD6pqNq9j=TzigMZJdGDYYeZHjM3N3FSqpV5hQhxJFMMe3KGg@mail.gmail.com&forum_name=tortoisehg-discuss) from the TortoiseHG mailing list:

> There are two things you miss by not running the installer:
>
> 1. Explorer extension (context menu, overlay icons)
> 2. Having the apps in your PATH (thg.exe, hg.exe, kdiff.exe, tortoiseplink.exe)
>
> The workbench and other apps should run just fine from a copy of the
>   install folder.
>
> --
>   Steve Borho

Answer (score 0):

Okay, my "initial reactions" aside, you might be able to copy the TortoiseHg folder after installing it to your machine then copying the Program Files directory a network location and run it from there. (At least, it appears to have been possible [in the past](http://www.selenic.com/pipermail/mercurial/2009-August/027273.html))

Try copying the Program Files\TortoiseHg directory to the network share (you could use a network drive to make your life in `cmd` easier)

Then run `thg.exe` with a shortcut/`cmd`/Run... prompt:

`<network location>\TortoiseHg\thg.exe`

Good luck!